# Removing the Approved/Rejected buttons

Tags: 2013, list

For some reason, one of my lists (in edit mode) has Approved/Rejected buttons next to the Save/Cancel buttons.  My users are accidentally hitting those and causing chaos.

I'm sure I can hide the buttons with JavaScript, but what's the `official` way to get rid of those?

Comment: Why you cannot turn off approval function on the list?

Comment: Approval is not required for new list items.  That was the first thing I checked.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, the easiest option to hide the Approve/Reject button from the Edit Form is inserting a JavaScript in the page to hide the buttons.

If you wish to do it in another proper way, here is a workaround for it

- Go to SharePoint Designer
- Open the Site
- Open the list where you need to do the changes
- Add a new Edit form to it
- Set the new Edit form as default

It is not required to do any modifications in the newly created Edit Form unless you wish to personalize it. By default the ‘Approve’ & ‘Reject’ button will not be shown in the Edit Form and you will be getting only ‘Save’ & ‘Cancel’ button.

Comment: I created a new Edit form in SPD, but didn't set it as default.  Still, it worked.  Do you know why this worked?  (I'll mark it as the solution once my users confirm this.)

Comment: It happens based on the Content type change when you create a new editform. If your list is associated only with 'Task' content type you will not get Approve/Reject button. But if yous list is also associated with 'Workflow task' content type, you will get the Approve/Reject button.

Comment: No, it didn't work across the board.  I ended up using JavaScript in a CEWP to hide the buttons.  Thanks anyway.  FWIW, this list is associated with a subtype of Task.